# How to make content fit minimum width, while maximum was set?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When the sentence is too big, there is a lot of white space left when collapsing it.

In the example below the word technician is too big for the div and is forced underneath, leaving a lot of space between appliance and the right border.

Is there a way to fix this with **CSS** or with **jQuery**?

[image: problem]

DIV Code:

```
width:28%;
float:left;
```

Comment: fix what???????? you defined the div width, what did u expect to happen?

Comment: I wanted to see if I could remove the extra space.

Comment: remove width to get that

Comment: I need the width to be set just below 30%.

Comment: @FlashThunder, mariusz [That won't work.](https://jsfiddle.net/x7hunerv/)

Comment: Interesting :-) Removing my -1.

Comment: There may be a jQuery solution for this, can ask for it and add tag RomanK?

Comment: Yes go ahead @skobaljic

Comment: Added jQuery tag, please vote to reopen, we may find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To break a word at any point line wraps then use `word-break` property of CSS with value `break-all`.

```
div {
  float: left;
  with: 28%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Example:

```css
div {
  background-color: #f00;
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Electrical Appliance Technician
</div>
```

If you want to hide the extra part with `...` so do it like:

```css
div {
  background-color: #f00;
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Electrical Appliance Technician
</div>
```

Comment: that's not an answer imo